# Case class with function as parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I have defined 3 case classes as follows:

```
case class Func1(inputA: HashMap[String, String], mapFn: (String, String) => List[(String, Int)], redFn: (String, List[Int]) => (String, Int))
case class Func2(inputB: HashMap[String, String], mapFn: (String, String) => List[(String, String)], redFn: (String, List[String]) => (String, List[String])) 
case class Func3(inputC: HashMap[String, String], mapFn: (String, String) => List[(String, String)], redFn: (String, List[String]) => (String, Int))
```

and in the receive method, I have the corresponding cases that match those above:

```
case Func1(inputA, mapFn, redFn) =>  // Do something
case Func2(inputB, mapFn, redFn) =>  // Do something
case Func3(inputC, mapFn, redFn) =>  // Do something
```

Is it possible to replace the 3 case classes with one generic case class?

I tried the following:

I defined the case class as follows:

```
case class Func[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))
```

Then, in the receive method of the MyActor class, I have:

```
case Func[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))  =>  //code here
```

The compile errors are as follows. The first error indicates that the error is at the `=>` in  `mapFn: (K,V) => List[(X,Y)]`

```
  ')' expected but '=>' found.

  [error]   case MapIt[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K,V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))  =>
```

The second error indicates that the problem is in the last square bracket (before the comma) of "mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)],"

```
  '=>' expected but ']' found.

  [error]   case Func[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))  =>
```

Comment: whats the problem with your method?

Comment: I am getting a compiler error:

Comment: Does your first solution of having three case classes work?

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if it was even possible to do what I am looking to do.  To answer your first question, I get a compile error:

')' expected but '=>' found.
[error]   case Func[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))  =>

'=>' expected but ']' found.
[error]   case Func[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))  =>

Comment: I am working on 3 MapReduce problems.  Right now, I give my app an input, a map function, and a reduce function and it does the MapReduce job. However, I was told to make it general and I thought that the way I was doing it, I would need to add a case class for any new map/reduce functions.  I was told that "make it general" meant that one case class should handle all cases.

Answer (score 1):

let me know, if this helps.

```
 case class FuncG[K, V, X, Y, U](input: HashMap[K, V], mapFn: (K, V) => List[(X, Y)], redFun: (X, List[Y]) => (X, U))   
  val firstParam: HashMap[String, String] = HashMap("test key" -> "test value")

  def mapfn1(a1:String, a2:String):List[(String, Int)] = List(("val1",4))
  def mapfn2(a1:String, a2:String):List[(String, String)] = List(("val2","val3"))

  def redfn1(r1:String, r2:List[Int]):(String, Int) = ("val4",56)
  def redfn2(r1:String, r2:List[String]):(String, List[String]) = ("val4",List("val5"))
  def redfn3(r1:String, r2:List[String]):(String, Int) = ("val6",34)

  val pattern1 = FuncG(firstParam,mapfn1,redfn1)
  val pattern2 = FuncG(firstParam,mapfn2,redfn2)
  val pattern3 = FuncG(firstParam,mapfn2,redfn3)

  def doMatch(pattern:Any) = {
    pattern match {
      case FuncG(inputA, mapFn, redFun)  =>  println("Found")
    }
  }

  doMatch(pattern1)
  doMatch(pattern2)
  doMatch(pattern3)
```

Comment: No, I couldn't get this to work either.  Perhaps there is no answer, and I am not approaching this correctly.